# Trace method in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I want Combobox 2 to display diffrent values depending on the state of a 1 Combobox. Combobox 2 also changes the state of a Entry box. What I don't understand is why the on_field_change function work's without a problem but the check_website one gives me a `TypeError: trace_variable() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'` error. Why? Any suggestions?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


main = tk.Tk()
app = tk.Frame(main)
app.grid()


def on_field_change(index, value, op):
    if novel.get() in has_book_website1:
        book_number_chosen.configure(state="enabled")
    else:
        book_number_chosen.configure(state="disabled")


def check_website(index, value, op):
    if website.get() == "Website1":
        novel_chosen["values"] = namelist_website1
    elif website.get() == "Website2":
        novel_chosen["values"] = namelist_website2


website = tk.StringVar
website_chosen = ttk.Combobox(app, width=42, textvariable=website,                         
                 state="readonly")
website.trace("w", check_website)
website_chosen["values"] = ["Website1", "Website12"]
website_chosen.current(0)
website_chosen.grid(column=1, row=0)

book_number = tk.IntVar()
book_number_chosen = ttk.Entry(app, width=5, textvariable=book_number,             
state="disabled")


novel = tk.StringVar()
novel_chosen = ttk.Combobox(app, width=42, textvariable=novel, 
               state="readonly")
novel.trace("w", on_field_change)
novel_chosen["values"] = ["1", "2"]
novel_chosen.grid(column=1, row=1)
novel_chosen.current(0)

has_book_website1 = ["2"]

namelist_website1 = ["Just", "some", "text"]
namelist_website2 = ["lorem", "ipsum"]

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: please create a [mcve] rather than a bunch of disconnected blocks of code.

Comment: Edited the post, was in a rush and hoped when I come back someone white knight would come across with a solution.

Comment: Do you aware of a missing parentheses in the end of a line `website = tk.StringVar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply because you wrote `website = tk.StringVar` instead of `website = tk.StringVar()`.

Why exactly does it result in this error?

You assign the `website` variable to the `tk.StringVar` **class**, while you actually want to assign it to an **instance** of it (created by the call with parentheses).
The `tk.StringVar.trace` method is more or less defined as follows:

```
class StringVar(...):
    ...
    def trace(self, mode, callback):
        ...
```

Since `website` points to the **class**, `website.trace` refers to the **class method**.
So when you call `website.trace("w", check_website)`, `"w"` is passed as `self`, and `check_website` as `mode`, and the call lacks an argument.

On the other hand, if `website` is defined as an **instance** of `tk.StringVar`, `website.trace` refers to the **instance method**, and `website` is implicitly passed as `self`.

Append those parentheses and you're good.